# Vue dynamic component forces <transition appear> to fire on page refresh

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm using the dynamic `<component>` in a loop to render all components. The first visible component in the page is using `<transition name="slide-in" appear>`. The animation fires correctly when navigating to the page. However the animation fires again when the user refreshes the page. This behaviour does not happen when I'm not using said component.

```
<div 
    class="component-wrapper
    v-for="(slice, index) in slices"
>
    <component
        :is="slice.slice_type"
        :slice="slice"
        :key="index
    />
</div>
```

Is there any way to adjust this behaviour?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

The `appear` prop causes the transition to run on initial render, and the component is rendered whenever the user refreshes the page. If you want to run the transition on initial render, but then turn it off after it's played once you might want to bind appear to some variable `:appear='first'` and  then use `@after-appear` to set that to false after the first page load.

```
<template :appear="first" @after-appear="rendered">
```

In order to make sure that the variable's initial value is remembered, you could put it into your vuex store and access it with a getter, and a mutation mutation/action that indicates that the transition has already been run.

```
first () { return store.getters.first_render }
rendered () { store.dispatch('falsify_first_render') }
```